# Предложение с местоимением и деепричастным оборотом

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли здесь ошибка в построении предложения с деепричастным оборотом: "Моя цель на сегодня — умереть, разрядив дробовик себе в голову"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложение построено верно:

*Моя цель на сегодня — **умереть, разрядив** дробовик себе в голову.*

Сказуемое выражено инфинитивом, к нему относится деепричастный оборот.
Это допускается правилами.

§212. Деепричастные обороты  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#%D0%B7_02

В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не выражающего действия подлежащего:

1)       если производитель действия, обозначенного **деепричастием**, совпадает с производителем действия, обозначенного другой глагольной формой (**инфинитивом,** причастием, деепричастием).

Здесь оба действия относятся к одному лицу.